# How to translate these loanwords in German?

Tags: english-to-german, loanword, english

Daily I use English `loanwords` in German emails. Then I found this forum and so I would like to ask what the best German translations would be for these words (if any) sothat I don't need to use the English words and use as much as possible German words. These words relate to the health of LCD monitors of very large formats.

```
"Matted display screen (non glossy)" = ..................
"Dead pixels and dead sub pixels" = .....................
"Evenness of illumination" = ............................
"Aging, shifting colortemperature" = ....................
"Decay in CCFL lamp life" = .............................
```

Comment: Wo sind hier loanwords zu sehen? Was davon ist nicht in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagbar? Diese Seite ist nicht als Gratis-Übersetzungsdienst gedacht. Wo ist die eigene Leistung?

Answer (score 6):

"Matted display screen (non glossy)" = 
ein matter Bildschirm / die matte Bildschirmoberfläche (matted screen surface)

"Dead pixels and dead sub pixels" = 
das schwarze Pixel/Subpixel, 
more general (including other types of pixel defects): der Pixelfehler, plural: die Pixelfehler.

"Evenness of illumination" = 
die Gleichmäßigkeit der Ausleuchtung / die gleichmäßige Ausleuchtung

"Aging, shifting colortemperature" = 
die Alterung, die alterungsbedingte Farbtemperaturveränderung 
(aging-related change of color temperature)

"Decay in CCFL lamp life" = 
Lebensdauerverkürzung der Kaltkathodenlampe/Bildschirmhintergrundbeleuchtung, 
das Abfallen der Lampenlebensdauer

Comment: "Ausleuchtung" = guter Begriff, gefällt mir

Answer (score 4):

here my translation proposal:

"Matted display screen (non glossy)" => matter Bildschirm (nicht spiegelnd)

"Dead pixels and dead sub pixels" => Fehlerhafte Pixel und Subpixel

"Evenness of illumination" => gleichmäßige Beleuchtung

"Aging, shifting colortemperature" => alternde, wechselnde Farbtemperatur

"Decay in CCFL lamp life" => Lebensende der CCFL-Lampe